# Longest unique chains in a graph with edges that follow some criteria

Tags: algorithm, graph

### Problem

This is a portion of a graph I ended up with in a problem I am trying to solve. For illustration purposes this will do -

[image]

The red line marks the a chain where all the edges have a weight that obeys a criterion (in this case: 60<weight<90)

I want to find all such chains in a graph like this. As an example, if the weight condition was - 105<weight<205 then all the chains I would want to find would be like this-

[image]

**Edit** This might be a clear mathematical statement of the problem

[image]

### My Attempts

##### 1

The gist of my naive approach was to -

1. loop through each vertex
2. loop through all of the edges and see if any of them fall within the criterion
3. If any of them are yes, initiate a "chain" array which stores the current vertex
4. Go to the other end of this edge and repeat steps 2-4
5. If we reach a vertex where none of the edges fall within the criterion, stop the search
6. Continue step 2 from the previous vertex ignoring the edges that have been checked.
7. Join chains together if there are any common vertices (split each chain at the common vertex and join the first part of the first chain with the second part of the second chain and the first part of the second chain to the second part of the first chain) (A->B->C->D and E->C->F will produce two new chains A->B->C->F and E->C->D)
8. Remove any redundancy like subchains saved as separate chains

I tried doing this in MATLAB, and it was taking an absurdly long time for my dataset of >5000 vertices. Since this looks like it might go to O(n<sup>4</sup>), I wasn't very surprised.

---

##### 2

I tried to transform it into some other problem and see if a solution existed but I couldn't figure that out. This might become **like** a multiple travelling salesman problem if instead of finding the shortest path I need to follow these criteria-

1. You can only give each of them a fixed gas allowance per day thus limiting the distance they can travel in a day (Edge weight must follow some criteria)
2. They do not need to return to the starting city (only chains)
3. Multiple salesmen visiting the same city is okay, more profit (multiple paths overlapping in part is allowed)

Then I could make a subgraph by removing all the edges (below, for example-2) that do not follow the criteria and then I would try to find the shortest distance in each maximally connected subgraph but I don't think this approach makes a lot of sense.

[image]

---

##### 3

Another idea I had was that in these maximally connected subgraphs, I could also try constructing the MST for each of them and then traverse from each leaf node to every other leaf node. I haven't been able to fully implement it correctly yet, but it still seems like it might have a really bad worst-case complexity.

---

##### 4

I also tried to look for patterns in the adjacency matrix but I couldn't identify any.

---

##### 5

In hopes of again transforming it into a different problem, I also tried changing the vertices into edges and edges into vertices giving me a graph looking like this (red line marks the same path as example 1) -

[image]

This just seems to make the problem more complicated.

---

Those are all of the things I have attempted. I don't know much about graph theory, so this might be a simple, well-established problem that I just don't know how to look for. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your goal to find any way of breaking those edges apart into chains, or do you want the minimum number of chains? The longest chains? Something else?

Comment: @templatetypedef the information I need from the chains is the total number of such chains in the graph and the length of those chains. But this is part of a bigger problem and based on what observations I have from my dataset I might need to know other things. Hence it is better if I have a way of breaking the graph into chains.

Comment: There may be many different ways of breaking the graph into chains, as I understand it. What happens if there are multiple such ways? Which way would you want?

Comment: Do you mean multiple ways that give me different kinds of chains? At the end of the day I want (as a chain is) a set of vertices V={v1,v2,…,vn} such that there exists one edge between vi and vi+1 where the edge weight is between two values and V is not a subset of any other chain

Comment: The first step is to remove all edges that don't meet the criteria. Then, for each remaining connected component (as in the third image), you need to solve the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). That is a NP-hard problem, made worse by the fact that you also want to find paths that aren't the longest (like the CDE path). So the only hope is that the graph always decomposes into simple subgraphs, after removing the non-conforming edges.

Comment: @user3386109 I have two questions - Can it perform better if I ignore paths such as CDE? If I want to find simple paths, then how would it get both IHGDE and IHGDC?

Comment: If the subgraph is a tree (no cycles), then you can find all of the paths easily. There's a path between every pair of vertices of degree 1. C, E, and I all have degree 1, so there are paths from C to E, C to I, and E to I. But if the subgraph has cycles (for example if C has an edge to H), then it can be hard to find the longest path. And if you aren't just looking for a single longest path, there may be a large number paths.